# Linear regression to predict the dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, prediction, r-squared, predictor

I have posted the summary of my model below. My predictor variable is significant. However, the $R^2$ value is very low. Can I use its intercept and slope to predict my response variable?

```
Call:
lm(formula = Deviated_toa_values_for_CA ~ Water_vapor_quantity_kg.m2)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.050961 -0.000923  0.002036  0.003636  0.006449 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                -0.0069993  0.0031336  -2.234   0.0279 *
Water_vapor_quantity_kg.m2  0.0002367  0.0001036   2.285   0.0245 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.007471 on 94 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.05264,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.04256 
F-statistic: 5.223 on 1 and 94 DF,  p-value: 0.02454
```

Comment: How can you say that the $R^2$ is low without a point of comparison?  Low in comparison to what?  In any case, if you want to know if you're model is useful for prediction, why not measure that directly, with cross validation?  Did you make a scatter plot of your data with the fit regression line overlayed?  That will tell you a lot more than this bag of numbers spit out from `lm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to use your model for forecasting, having significant coefficients should not be that much concern. If you use it for inference (hypothesis testing), then it should be a concern.
- If your are confused how significant results could lead to low R-Squared, *simply* think in this way: I am 95% confident that my independent variable also could explain 5% of the variation of my dependent variable in the population.
- As it is mentioned in the comment, you should use accuracy measures for forecasting.
- If you have a time series, why don't you use time series models? `auto.arima` is a good function to work with. `Water_vapor_quantity_kg.m2` could be an exogenous variable in your ARIMA model.

Comment: Where does OP say that they have a time series?

Comment: Fair point, but I put "If" at the beginning.